# Display previous selected rows - Multichoice DialogBox Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using Multichoice dialog box , I am able to display dialog box ,select/unselect rows but I am not able to display previously selected rows .
Here is my code

```
final CharSequence[] items = eventTypeStr.split(",");    
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setTitle("Event Types")
                        .setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {

                            }
                        }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel
                            }
                        }).create();
                dialog.show();
```

I visited many related post over stackoverflow . Few are saying , save states(select/unselect) in preferences , I can save in preferences , but how can I display those saved pereferences(select/unselect) in Multichoice Dialog Box when dialog box will open again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by DarkShadow helped me but it is not fully matching the requirements .
After learning AlertDialog API I found my answer .
Previously I was passing null as the second argument of **setMultiChoiceItems** now second argument will be boolean array of selected/unselected items . That's what I needed .
Updated code should be :

```
    final CharSequence[] items = eventTypeStr.split(",");    
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setTitle("Event Types")
                        .setMultiChoiceItems(items, arrayOfCheckedUncheckedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {

                            }
                        }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel
                            }
                        }).create();
                dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected item you just have to add some code inside the onClick() method of DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(). After adding code your onClick method should look something like that.

Declare a list to which you can add the index of selected items

```
List mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
if (isChecked) {
                   // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                   mSelectedItems.add(indexSelected);
               } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                   // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                   mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
               }

}
```

Now you know the index of all the selected items so you can easily find the corresponding values also. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Man for your efforts , your efforts helped me . I posted my answer please check .